# How to find the median value of NSNumbers in an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, key-value

I'm trying to calculate the median of a (small) set of NSNumbers in an NSArray. Every object in the NSArray is a NSNumber.

Here is what I'm trying, but it's not working:

```
NSNumber *median = [smallNSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@median.floatValue"];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
NSArray *sorted = [smallNSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];    // Sort the array by value
NSUInteger middle = [sorted count] / 2;                                           // Find the index of the middle element
NSNumber *median = [sorted objectAtIndex:middle];                                   // Get the middle element
```

You can get fancier. For example, the median of a set with an even number of numbers is technically the average of the middle *two* numbers. You could also wrap this up into a neat one-line method in a category on `NSArray`:

```
@interface NSArray (Statistics)
- (id)median;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Statistics)

- (id)median
{
    return [[self sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] objectAtIndex:[self count] / 2];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who has the unusual need for this function, here's a category method on NSArray that will work with both an odd and an even number of elements:

#### NSARRAY CATEGORY METHOD

```c
- (float)median {
    if (self.count == 1) return [self[0] floatValue];

    float result = 0;
    NSUInteger middle;

    NSArray * sorted = [self sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    if (self.count % 2 != 0) {  //odd number of members
        middle = (sorted.count / 2);
        result = [[sorted objectAtIndex:middle] floatValue];
    }
    else {
        middle = (sorted.count / 2) - 1;
        result = [[@[[sorted objectAtIndex:middle], [sorted objectAtIndex:middle + 1]] valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"] floatValue];
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### TEST

```
NSArray * singleElement = @[@1];
NSArray * oddNumberOfElements = @[@3, @5, @7, @12, @13, @14, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @29, @39, @40, @56];
NSArray * evenNumberOfElements = @[@3, @5, @7, @12, @13, @14, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @29, @40, @56];

NSLog(
    @"oddNumberOfElements: %f, evenNumberOfElements: %f singleElement: %f",
    [oddNumberOfElements median], [evenNumberOfElements median], [singleElement median]
);
//oddNumberOfElements: 20.000000, evenNumberOfElements: 19.500000 singleElement: 1.000000
```

Comment: You are picking the wrong index in the odd case and even worse; the code crashes when the length of the array is 1.

Comment: @JKvr, thanks! Careless... Amended method and added test code.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Extension**

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

  var median: Element {
    return self.sort(<)[self.count / 2]
  }

}
```

Comment: As some said above for an even number of Items, this wont work correctly.